# Winterbash notification button not appearing

Tags: bug, winter-bash

## Winterbash snowflake doesn't appear

Title says most of it.  Sometimes when I visit a SE page, any page, the snowflake icon at the top doesn't appear for a bit.

All the time it takes a second or two to load, but sometimes it doesn't load at all, or takes like 30 seconds to a minute.

I checked my internet speed and it doesn't seem to be a problem (≥65 mbs).  I wanted to know if this was a known bug, or not.

I am using Chrome v47 on OS X 10.8.5. (Yes, I know, even mavericks is better than this, but my computer is too old for that (2009))

Comment: Related: [Don't move all the cheese for this snowflake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304516/335251)